# html elements alignment issues

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to put an image before the `input` element but they don't align properly and there is no padding or margins applied at all. Let me know why are they out of sync and how to fix it

```
<div data-postid="14" data-category="link" data-userid="1" 
data-lastcommentid="0">
<img src="images/minicons-06-512.png" height="25" width="25"> 
<input type="text" placeholder="comment" > 
<input type="hidden" value="14">
<input type="hidden" value="link"> <input type="hidden" value="5">
<input type="hidden" value="1"> </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n2j0nxo8/

Comment: so.. what do you mean by properly?

Comment: @Pepo_rasta I mean the image is a bit up than the lower bottom where the text box is touching

Comment: @sajanyamaha What if I knew but I am tired... and could not figure out what mistake I am making... you are reported.. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following css to align properly.

```css
img,
div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div data-postid="14" data-category="link" data-userid="1" data-lastcommentid="0">
  <img src="images/minicons-06-512.png" height="25" width="25">
  <input type="text" placeholder="comment">
  <input type="hidden" value="14">
  <input type="hidden" value="link">
  <input type="hidden" value="5">
  <input type="hidden" value="1">
</div>
```

See demo .
http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_programmer/n2j0nxo8/2/

Answer (score 1):

Well you could always add this inline or to the CSS.

`style="display:inline;"`

Are you trying to get the top border level?

Answer (score 1):

Just a little float in the image by css:

http://jsfiddle.net/pmjv5shL/

```css
img {
    display: block;
    float: left;    
}
```

```html
<div data-postid="14" data-category="link" data-userid="1" data-lastcommentid="0"> 
  <img src="images/minicons-06-512.png" height="25" width="25"> 
  <input type="text" placeholder="comment" > 
  <input type="hidden" value="14">
  <input type="hidden" value="link"> 
  <input type="hidden" value="5"> 
  <input type="hidden" value="1"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following fiddle. It has been fixed.

http://jsfiddle.net/aalok/n2j0nxo8/4/

It appears that `vertical-align: middle;` to the img fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`css line-height`**

```
<div data-postid="14" data-category="link" data-userid="1" data-lastcommentid="0">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/25/25/" height="25" width="25">
    <input type="text" placeholder="comment" style="line-height: 25px">
    <input type="hidden" value="14"><input type="hidden" value="link">
    <input type="hidden" value="5">
    <input type="hidden" value="1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just:

```
img, div {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nickthename/tw11r6jL/1/)